# R user function to run gmm model repeatedly using pgmm function

Tags: r, plm, gmm

I have created a function to run gmm model repeatedly using pgmm function from plm package. here is the code.

````
```
   run.gmm <- function(data,
              predictor,
              dep,
              controls,
              row.name = predictor,
              add.controls = NULL,
              rm.controls = NULL,
              caption = NULL, model, effect, transformation) {
     gmodel <-
              return.model.gmm(data,
                 predictor,
                 dep,
                 controls,
                 add.controls,
                 rm.controls, model, effect, transformation)
    if (Console == T) {
       print(summary(gmodel, robust = TRUE, time.dummies = TRUE))
     }
      invisible(gmodel)
      }

     return.model.gmm <- function(data, predictor, dep, controls, add.controls = NULL, 
                                  rm.controls = NULL, effect, model, mtransformation) {
                 controls <- controls[!controls %in% rm.controls]
                 controls <- paste("lag(", c(controls, add.controls), ",1)", collapse = " + ")
                 predictors <- paste(predictor, controls, sep = " + ")
                 formula <- paste(dep, predictors, sep = " ~ ")
                 gmmodel <- pgmm(formula, paste("|", controls), data = data, effect = effect, 
                             model = model, transformation = transformation)
                 return(gmmodel)
         } 
     ```
````

with above, now I plugged the arguments:

```
my.controls <- c("lnPDENS", "GDPGR", "LFSGR", 'GRRAT')
my.predictor = paste("lag(", c("LaPGrowth", "SRate"), ",1)", collapse = " + ")
my.effect <- c("twoways")
my.model <- c("twosteps")
my.transformation <- c("ld")

run.gmm(data=pdata.lbprt, dep="LaPGrowth", predictor = my.predictor, controls = my.controls, effect=my.effect, 
       model=my.model, transformation=my.transformation)
```

I get the following error:

Error in match.arg(effect) :
'arg' should be one of “twoways”, “individual”

Any idea, where my code is wrong. I believe the error can be detected even without sample data.

Greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could solve the problem. It was really worth spending time. Here is the final code:

```
require(Formula)
require(magrittr)
require(plm)

run.gmm <- function(data,
                  predictor,
                  dep,
                  controls,
                  row.name = predictor,
                  add.controls = NULL,
                  rm.controls = NULL,
                  caption = NULL, effect, model, transformation) {
 gmodel <-
  return.model.gmm(data,
                     predictor,
                     dep,
                     controls,
                     add.controls,
                     rm.controls, effect, model, transformation)
 if (Console == T) {
  print(summary(gmodel, robust = TRUE, time.dummies = TRUE))
 }
 invisible(gmodel)
}

return.model.gmm <- function(data, predictor, dep, controls, add.controls = NULL, 
                         rm.controls = NULL, effect, model, mtransformation) {
  
             controls <- controls[!controls %in% rm.controls]
             controls <- paste("lag(", c(controls, add.controls), ",1)", collapse = " + ")
             predictors <- paste(predictor, paste(controls, sep = " + "), sep='+')
             formula <- paste(dep, predictors, sep = " ~ ")
             multipart <- paste(formula, "|", controls)
             multipartformula <- Formula::Formula(as.formula(multipart))
             gmmodel <- pgmm(multipartformula, data = data, effect = effect, model = 
                         model, transformation = transformation)
    
       return(gmmodel)
}
```

Notice the changes. I have used Formula function from Formula package to incorporate multipart formula object. Also, note the changes in 'predictors'. The function works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up the order of `model` and `effect`:

#### `run.gmm`

```r
return.model.gmm(data,          #1
                 predictor,     #2
                 dep,           #3
                 controls,      #4
                 add.controls,  #5
                 rm.controls,   #6
                 model,         #7
                 effect,        #8
                 transformation #9
)
```

#### `return.model.gmm`

```r
return.model.gmm <- function(
   data,                #1
   predictor,           #2
   dep,                 #3
   controls,            #4
   add.controls = NULL, #5
   rm.controls = NULL,  #6
   effect,              #7
   model,               #8
   mtransformation      #9
)
```

When you call `return.model.gmm` you pass `effect` as the `8th` parameter, while when you define `return.model.gmm` ot os the `7th` parameter.

Thus, calling the function `return.model.gmm` like this should do the trick:

```r
return.model.gmm(data,          #1
                 predictor,     #2
                 dep,           #3
                 controls,      #4
                 add.controls,  #5
                 rm.controls,   #6
                 effect,        #7
                 model,         #8
                 transformation #9
)
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. I didn't realize order of parameters do have effect. I have corrected this but now new error is showing. this is 

``` Error in Formula(formula) : inherits(object, "formula") is not TRUE 
```

Checking error line shows it is in this line of codes: 
```
gmmodel <- pgmm(formula, paste("|", controls), data = data, effect = effect, 
                             model = model, transformation = transformation)
```

Comment: Got you. Now new error is showing

Error in x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms") %||% stop("no terms component nor attribute") : 
no terms component nor attribute

I was concerned about how to introduce multi-part formula like the following: 

pgmm(LaPGrowth ~ lag(LaPGrowth,1)+ lag(SRate, 1) +lag(lnPDENS,1)+lag(GDPGR,1)+lag(LFSGR,1)+lag(GRRAT,1)
                    | lag(lnPDENS, 1) + lag(GDPGR,1)+lag(LFSGR,1)+lag(GRRAT,1),
                    data = pdata.lbprt, effect = "twoways", model = "twosteps", transformation = "ld")

The above is if you run gmm without creating user function.

Comment: Please provide a proper [reprex] of your problem and also consider [this article on what to do if somebody answers your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I think the problem now boils down to construct a multi-part formula object, something using Formula. Here is an useful article https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Formula/vignettes/Formula.pdf